# MassTransit + Kafka - Fault consumer not being called

Tags: apache-kafka, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit 8.0.10 along with Kafka as a rider, and what I'm trying to accomplish is to handle messages that couldn't be processed by an error condition, and do something with them (like logging them to a dead letter topic.

Here's what I have done so far:

- Configure a retry policy for my Kafka consumer. Done ✅

```
Action<IRetryConfigurator> retryConfigurator = configurator =>
            {
                configurator.Incremental(
                        2,
                        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000),
                        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));
            };
```

- Created and registered a generic Fault consumer following this page https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/exceptions#consuming-faults. ✅

```
internal class FaultConsumer<TMessage> : IConsumer<Fault<TMessage>>
        where TMessage : class
```

```
massTransit.AddConsumer<FaultConsumer<TMessageType>>(); //massTransit is IRegistrationConfigurator
```

- When retries are exhausted, I can see a FAULT message in my console log. ✅

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp9OC.png)

So far I haven't been able to get my fault consumer to kick in.

What am I missing?
Is this functionality supported when using MassTransit with Kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faults are neither published nor produced, and messages in a Kafka topic are not copied to an *_error* topic.

Comment: Thank you Chris. Is there anything in MassTransit that could help me implement what I'm trying to do? I was able to write custom error handling code checking retry counts, but wanted to try some of the framework concepts. Great work with this library by the way!

Comment: Also for clarification - what faults is this referring to? https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/exceptions#consuming-faults

Comment: `Fault<T>` is only published for broker-based (RabbitMQ, Azure Service Bus, etc.) consumer exceptions.